# Compare two arraylist of different types

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 array-list called assignment and person and both of different type and different sizes also. 
Problem statement :I wanna remove items from person where person id equals assignment id,
i hv written following Comparator.

```
SortedSet<Map.Entry<AssignmentResults, Person>> text = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<AssignmentResults, Person>>(
        new Comparator<Map.Entry<AssignmentResults, Person>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<AssignmentResults, Person> lhs,
                    Entry<AssignmentResults, Person> rhs) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int statusvalue = 0;

                if (rhs.getValue().getId()
                        .equals(lhs.getKey().getId()))
                    statusvalue = 1;

                return statusvalue;
            }

        });
```

But i m not sure how to use this to get person arraylist where all item which does not contains assignment id will be removed.plz any help will be appreciated. 
I need logic which is robust with less complexity

Comment: 1) do you want to really compare arrays, or just remove items from person where person id equals to assignment id? 2) Are you using ArrayList or Map?

Comment: i m looking for faster implementation of code i dont wanna write for loop for (){ for(){ }} whoes complexity will be nsquare

Comment: Then pre-sort your list and implement a binary search for log(n)^2 = n.

Comment: Use Set, Put all ids of assignment in a set. Now iterate over the person array and try to insert its ids into the same set. If its already present in set, remove it from person array.
This will be O(n) solution

Comment: @christopher u mean sort both the list and do for loop search?

Comment: @Monicka are you using ArrayList or Map?

Comment: assignment and persons both are arrylist

Comment: No. I mean a [Binary Search Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: @christopher ok , can u tell me what will be complexity then?

Answer (score 0):

You can save all assigments' ids to `HashSet` and then remove items from list of persons with `for-loop`:

```
Set<Long> assigmentsIdsSet = new HashSet<Long>(); // here we will store all assigments' ids

for (AssignmentResults assigment : assigmentsList) { // assigmentsList is your array list of assigments
    assigmentsIdsSet.add(assigment.getId());
}

// now go through list of persons and remove persons with ids from assigmentsIdsSet
for (Iterator<Person> it = personList.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    if (assigmentsIdsSet.contains(it.next().getId())) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

1. There is no way how the code above could throw an `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception
2. It has linear complexity on the size of arrays

Comment: but i said assignment and person size are different it will throw array out of bound exception

Comment: @Venu what abt array out of bound exception

Comment: based on arraylist size only we are comparing those two list then why should we get arrayout of bound exception ?

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing: you intend to work on lists and you compare map entries.

You could just:

- Have your `Person` and `Assignment` classes both implement a common interface with `getId`.
- Overide `equals` in both classes so that objects with the same id are equal. You would cast `Object` parameters to instances of your common interface with `getId`.
- You should also overide `hashCode` so that objects with the same id have the same hashcode. You could just return `getId().getHashCode()` if id is an object.
- You can then do `persons.removeAll(assignments)`

As a side note, all of this is not really "clean"; but it would get the job done for that specific use case. Just don't rely on this if you intend to provide a library with many other use cases

Comment: m just trying to give caparator both AssignmentResults, Person if u hv better than this code snip plz provide